# How to define Strong Name signing and post-build event commands by default for all projects in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

For the assembly signing process (strong name, ClickOnce, code signing, post-build event commands), I have to manually edit every single project within every single solution to set the signing related project settings. I am also churn out new projects, and this manual signing configuration process takes a long time (in relation) and sometimes introduce issues (typos, etc.).

Is there a way to setup "default" signing settings with Visual Studio 2017 that automatically applies to *newly* created solutions and its projects?

Also I like to extend the question: Can I also use the non-shared (non-Git) user based configuration (e.g. `WindowsApp1.vbproj.user`) for such signing settings? For example to overwrite the default settings with e.g. a individual developer code signing certificate.